# Did Master Stone Masons have to Bow to the King?

Tags: history, united-kingdom, culture

I have heard this multiple times, including in a [documentary](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00rfjd4) once. The claim is that the Master Stonemason, in historic times, did not have to bow to the King (generally implied to be from the British master Stonemason to the British King) [1](https://twitter.com/jkeyes/status/246718594627559424), [2](https://www.facebook.com/danielmerriweather/posts/10153151575170613).

> **The Stonemason was the master of all craftsmen. And it is telling that
>   the master stonemason did not have to bow to his monarch.** - ([Montey Don, Mastercrafts - E6 - Stonemasonry, 14th Minute](https://youtu.be/Xd2AprD7sRM?t=846))

  -

Comment: Might get a better answer on History.SE

Comment: Possibly. Looking into it cross posting is not allowed for some reason. But I am also unsure how long it is best to wait for an answer. No idea what the average answering time is. I have explored other options for getting an answer, so I think I will give everyone a few days.

Also, this question does sort of fit Skeptics better, as it is asking about the veracity of a crazy rumor.

Comment: "cross posting is not allowed for some reason" - such as getting (and possibly accepting) two contradictory answers?